# Russian Visa - Spanish vs British Passport - is there any benefit to having it in one passport over the other?

Tags: visas, russia

I'm trying to help my boss sort out a Russian visa for a business trip
He has dual nationality and therefore two passports - British and Spanish.

Are there any advantages or disadvantages in using one of those passports over the other to get a Russian visa.

We are in the UK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the third-party visa processor, the fees for Spanish nationals are [rather lower](http://ru.vfsglobal.co.uk/business.html) than those for nationals of the UK.

Since I am unaware of any other significant difference, I would therefore get the visa with the Spanish passport.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a consideration: If there's any legal trouble in Russia (anything could happen), would your boss want a Spanish or a British consular representative helping him out?